# IOS - how to open a website after application is removed from device

Tags: ios

I am new to programming for iOS and need some guidance on how to link to a website after an app gets deleted. For example, when a user clicks the "X" button, removes the app and any data it stored, the code should open a website.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

No, Apple does not allow you to hook in the SpringBoard to detect app deletion.
There is no work around, it's not possible.